# Clojure nested tagged literals

Tags: clojure, literals

I'm trying to parse a nested structure of PriorityMaps:

```
(def reader-map
 {
   'util/pm (fn [x] (println "reading > " x) (parse-map x))
})

(binding [*data-readers* reader-map]
    (clojure.core/read-string "#util/pm \"{:z 4 :y #util/pm \"{:y 3 :x 3}\" :x 9}\""))
```

...but I don't see the nested string passed into my handler as I'd expect, only the string up to the first nested tag:

```
 reading >  {:z 4 :y #er.util.net/pm
```

what am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need more backslashes if you want nested quotes:

```
(binding [*data-readers* reader-map]
    (clojure.core/read-string "#util/pm \"{:z 4 :y #util/pm \\\"{:y 3 :x 3}\\\" :x 9}\""))
```

Comment: oh god so exponential levels of escaping ?

Comment: Yup, exponential backslash expansion! I really hope you weren't planning on nesting too many levels.

Comment: I was - am going to use another method now! Store as normal maps, post-process into PriorityMaps.

Comment: @Hendekagon the value associated with a tag doesn't have to be a string; it can be any normally readable Clojure data structure. Something like "#util/pm {:z 4 :y #util/pm {:y 3 :x 3}}" can work, AFAIK.

Comment: @JoostDiepenmaat, [the documentation](http://clojure.org/reader#The%20Reader--Tagged%20Literals) agrees with you. Looks like he'd just have to change the reader to accept a map rather than a string.

Comment: @JoostDiepenmaat & DaoWen - thankyou so much! I'd read the documentation and couldn't work out why I couldn't get it to work that way, hence resorting to strings, I just tried again and it works fine.